# Angular 5 securing all views with authentication

Tags: angular, angular5

I am learning Angular 5. I am using Azure ADAL to authenticate the users.

When the path is empty, I am routing the user to login page. If the user is not logged in yet we provide a login button, which when clicked takes the user to microsoft login page. Below is the code.

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule }             from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { LoginComponent }      from './login/login.component';
import { HomeComponent }      from './home/home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

@NgModule({
    exports: [RouterModule],
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

login.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Adal5Service } from 'adal-angular5';

const config = {
    tenant: 'xxxxxxx',
    clientId: 'xxxxxx'
}

@Component({
    selector: 'app-login',
    templateUrl: './login.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor (private service: Adal5Service) {
        this.service.init(config);
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.service.handleWindowCallback();

        if (this.service.userInfo.authenticated) {
            window.location.href = "home";
        }
    }

    public isLoggedIn () {
        return this.service.userInfo.authenticated;
    }

    public login () {
        this.service.login();
    }

}
```

login.component.html

```
<input type="text" placeholder="CWOPA" class="cwopa-field" />
<button class="login-button" (click)='login()'>Login</button>
```

But, when a user types the home screen url, the screen opens even though the user is not logged in. So I added a isLoggedIn() method in login.component.ts and I am calling it from home component's on init method. Below is the code

home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import {LoginComponent} from '../login/login.component'

@Component({
    selector: 'app-home',
    templateUrl: './home.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
    providers: [ LoginComponent ]
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    private loginComponent: LoginComponent;

    constructor(loginComponent: LoginComponent) { 
        this.loginComponent = loginComponent;
    }

    ngOnInit() {

        if (!this.loginComponent.isLoggedIn()) {
            window.location.href = '/login';
        }
    }

}
```

The same will be repeated in all components.

My problem is, whenever a new component is added and if the isLoggedIn method is not called from the component's on init method, the view is displayed without authentication. Is there a better way to secure all views in an application without having to write the code in component's on init method?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards

Comment: Also, starting with version 2 it's called Angular, not AngularJS. It's a complete rewrite and thus a different product. AngularJS refers only to version 1. The same goes for tags on questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Route Guards, here's an exemple:
Routing:

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';


import { MyProfileComponent } from './components/profile/my-profile/my-profile.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'profile/my-profile', component: MyProfileComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService] }
];

export const Routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

AuthGuardService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { SessionStorageService } from 'ngx-webstorage';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {

    constructor(public session: SessionStorageService, public router: Router) { }

    canActivate(): boolean {
        if (this.session.retrieve("login") == null) {
            this.router.navigate(['home']);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

So here the user can't navigate to the profile/my-profile unless it's authenticated.